# Input's value as variable is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Got an input type text. Whatever entered is supposed to become a value for variable, and further on from there. Yet, i get error "Uncaught ReferenceError: emailvar is not defined" and the whole script breaks from there.

html

```
<input type="text" class="signfield emfield" />
<div class="submt sbmtfrm" href="#" style="cursor:pointer;">Step 2</div>
```

and js

```
$(".sbmtfrm").click(function(){
   var emailvar = $(".emfield").val();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `emailvar` is being defined in a function [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), and only that function has access to it.

```
$(".sbmtfrm").click(function(){
   var emailvar = $(".emfield").val();
});
```

If you want to use `emailvar` outside of your jQuery event handler, you will need to first define it (not *assign* it, yet) outside the scope of the function.

```
(function(window, $) { // closure
    var emailvar;

    $(".sbmtfrm").click(function() {
        emailvar = $(".emfield").val();
    });

    // you now have access to `emailvar` in any function in this closure

}(window, jQuery));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare emailvar as a global variable to use it outside of that click event handler:

```
$(function()
{
    var emailvar;
    $(".sbmtfrm").click(function()
    {
       emailvar = $(".emfield").val();
    });
    function foo()
    {
        console.log(emailvar);
    }
}
```